# Haskell's Text.Regex.subRegex using TDFA implementation?

Tags: regex, haskell

Is there a way to use the TDFA implementation of Regex with the functions in Text.Regex such as subRegex? The documentation says that Text.Regex must use the POSIX implementation only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, I think you'll have to write your own subRegex using the match and substring splicing functions. Text.Regex is part of  regex-compat-0.92, which only works with the posix backend.

Answer (score 1):

It is available on Hackage the package [regex-compat-tdfa](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-compat-tdfa) that provides a `Text.Regex` implementation using TDFA.